# Compare row value for duplication in adjacent columns in a loop to clean data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

## Summary

```
0   101 2017/11 -9999.0 -7.60   -4.00   -9999.0 -9999.0 -4.00   -0.22   1.76    4.64    6.98    8.96    12.56   15.98   19.58   22.46   25.34   28.40   
1   101 2017/11 -9999.0 -7.78   -4.36   -9999.0 -9999.0 -4.36   -0.22   1.76    4.64    6.80    8.78    12.56   15.98   19.58   22.46   25.16   28.22
2   101 2017/11 -9999.0 -7.60   -4.18   -9999.0 -9999.0 -4.18   -0.22   1.76    4.46    6.80    8.78    12.56   15.98   19.58   22.46   25.16   28.22   
3   101 2017/11 -9999.0 -7.96   -5.26   -9999.0 -9999.0 -5.26   -0.40   1.76    4.46    6.80    8.60    12.38   15.98   19.58   22.46   25.16   28.22   
4   101 2017/11 -9999.0 -6.88   -4.36   -9999.0 -9999.0 -4.36   -0.40   1.58    4.46    6.80    8.60    12.38   15.98   19.58   22.46   25.16   28.22   
5   101 2017/11 20.30   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06
6   101 2017/11 19.76   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06
7   101 2017/11 20.30   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06   35.06
```

I need to be able to remove the data from columns where the adjacent column has the same exact number. So in this example columns 5, 6 and 7 would look like the following:

```
5 2017/11   20.30   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     
6 2017/11   19.76   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     
7 2017/11   20.30   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

## What I've tried

A lot of answers I found seem to transform and then indicate a Boolean value.

i was considering something like this psuedocode to check adjacent columns

```
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    rowvar = i
    if data.iloc[i] == rowvar:
        data.iloc[i] = np.nan
```

but it obviously doesn't work.

## Actual

`ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types`

Is there an easy way to do this that is maybe more Pythonic/Pandas?

Comment: Can you limit your question to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem? To me it's absolutely not clear what your actual problem is - or if there are several different problems. If so, try to pin them down step by step (and maybe ask additional, specific questions)

Comment: @ascripter totally valid point, it felt convoluted even as i was writing. I'll make an edit. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pandas.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) is indeed the right function for you. However you need to check across the columns *in both directions* if values are equal or not. This code sets all values to `NaN` if the previous *or* next column have the same value:

```
import numpy as np
data[np.logical_or(data.diff(axis=1) == 0, data.diff(axis=1, periods=-1) == 0)] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking up the `diff()` method on a pd.DataFrame. I believe it will give you a direction as to how to solve your problem.

Comment: that definitely opens up some ideas, i'll check it out.